# Identifying the correct tense

Tags: grammar

Im in beginer level of learning english and i want to learn english logically. 
Sometimes i know certain statements are correct but i dont know how to explain to someone.

As an example 
I am Jack,
My name is Linda,
I am 10 years old,
John is a teacher.

This sentence is grammatically correct
But when using am, is, are most of the time sentence should be verb+ing. 
Can anyone please explain grammer behind the 3 examples. Why 'am' can use without being present continuous and please mention various situations we use 
To be verbs without sentence being continuous.

Comment: *Be* and its various forms (am, is, are, etc) can be used in various ways, with different conventions. Here are a couple: In "I am a man", it identifies "I" with "a man"; in "I am winning", it acts as an auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 1):

All of these sentences are correct (except they should end in stop rather than a comma).  They are in the present-simple tense. This means that the action (being) occurs at present time but it carries no information about the completeness of the action.

You could write these sentences in present-continuous tense by changing the verb to "[am|is|are] being".  With the verb *to be*, the continuous tense implies that the the subject is **actively** playing the role of the object.  It is a common mistake for English learners to use the continuous tense to passively connect the subject and object.

For example, if your name is Jack you could say "I am Jack." but if you were an actor actively playing the part of Jack, you might say "I am being Jack."

"He is ten years old." is just a statement of his age but "He is being ten years old." means he is behaving as you would expect from a ten year-old.